# How to display parent Taxonomy ID in REST export

Tags: views, 8

I want to configure REST export View in which I display taxonomy term name, id and parent ID. How to insert parent taxonomy term id, why it's not available in FIELDS?

Here is current REST export settings, I only missing parent term ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not yet supported. We're working to add that capability in https://www.drupal.org/node/2543726.

Long story short: the `$term->parent` field is a special snowflake: it's *not* an entity reference field as you would expect!